# Paeth-transform arrays

Tags: code-golf, array

One of the key parts of PNG's compression algorithm is the *Paeth transformation,* which transforms the image in a way that makes it compress better (usually). In this challenge, your task is to write a program to compute a Paeth transformation. The operation of a Paeth transformation is described below.

### The Paeth Transformation

The Paeth transformation subtracts from each member `X` of a 2-dimensional array a predictor. The predictor is that element of the array member to the left (`A`), top (`B`), and top-left (`C`) of `X` whose value has the least difference to `A + B - C`.

```
┼─┼─┼
│C│B│
┼─┼─┼
│A│X│
┼─┼─┼
```

If one of `A`, `B`, or `C`, would be out of bounds, its value is replaced by 0. Here is pseudocode from the [PNG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Filters.html) outlining how this predictor is computed:

```
function PaethPredictor (a, b, c)
begin
     ; a = left, b = above, c = upper left
     p := a + b - c        ; initial estimate
     pa := abs(p - a)      ; distances to a, b, c
     pb := abs(p - b)
     pc := abs(p - c)
     ; return nearest of a,b,c,
     ; breaking ties in order a,b,c.
     if pa <= pb AND pa <= pc then return a
     else if pb <= pc then return b
     else return c
end
```

For this challenge, the array members are natural numbers in the range from 0 to 255. If the Paeth transformation results in a value outside of that range, it shall be reduced modulo 256 to a value in that range.

### Input and Output

The input is two integers *x* and *y* in the range from 2 to 1023 denoting width and height of the matrix to transform and an array of *x* × *y* elements. The input is formatted as decimal numbers separated by one blank character terminated with a linefeed. Here is what this input could look like:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This would represent a 2 by 3 matrix with the entries:

```
4 5
6 7
8 9
```

The output shall have the same format as the input with the relaxiation that the numbers may be separated by an arbitrary non-zero amount of whitespace characters (space, horizontal or vertical tab, line or form feed) and be terminated by an arbitrary amount of whitespace characters.

Input shall be received from `stdin`, output shall go to `stdout`. If this is not possible, choose a different way of receiving input and writing output that is not hard-coding the input.

The behaviour of your program when presented with invalid input is not part of this challenge.

### Judging and Reference Implementation

An ANSI C program [is provided](https://gist.github.com/fuzxxl/68bfc33ca05a1e381644/e16f1c3f3eb193cd876dfa1c9eef6ebb11d76d58) to generate sample input, solve instances and verify solutions. Call the program with `g` to **g**enerate input, with `s` to **s**olve an input instance and with `v` to **v**erify the correctness of a solution.

If you think the reference implementation is faulty, please let me know so I can correct it as soon as possible.

### Example input and output

By popular request.

```
10 5 166 156 108 96 63 227 122 99 117 135 125 46 169 247 116 55 151 1 232 114 214 254 6 127 217 88 206 102 252 237 75 250 202 145 86 198 172 84 68 114 58 228 66 224 186 217 210 108 11 179
```

representing the array

```
166 156 108  96  63 227 122  99 117 135
125  46 169 247 116  55 151   1 232 114
214 254   6 127 217  88 206 102 252 237
 75 250 202 145  86 198 172  84  68 114
 58 228  66 224 186 217 210 108  11 179
```

is transformed into

```
166 246 208 244 223 164 151 233  18  18
215 177 123  78 125  84  96 135 231 138
 89 129   8 121 101 228  55 101  20 123
117 175 196 199 125 112 222 238  72  46
239 234 120 158  41  19  12  24 183 111
```

which is encoded as

```
10 5 166 246 208 244 223 164 151 233 18 18 215 177 123 78 125 84 96 135 231 138 89 129 8 121 101 228 55 101 20 123 117 175 196 199 125 112 222 238 72 46 239 234 120 158 41 19 12 24 183 111
```

### Winning Condition

For this challenge, write a *program* that generates correct Paeth transformation of the input and writes them out. This is *code-golf,* the program with the least amount of characters in its source code wins. Please try to attach an explanation and a readable version of your code to your submission so others can see what it does.

Comment: What do you mean by "*If the Paeth transformation results in a value outside of that range*"? Since the result is always drawn from a set of three elements, all of which are within range, this seems to be covering an impossible case.

Comment: @PeterTaylor The Paeth transformation is for each array member the difference between the value of that member and the predictor for that member, which can be negative.

Comment: @MartinBüttner That must have slipped through the copy-editing.

Comment: @Alex whether 0 is a natural number highly depends on the author of your textbook.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Truth. Didn't realize there isn't universal agreement on that until a moment ago. But that was a total aside. Nice challenge.

Comment: @Alex I'm happy that you like it. Let's see if people appreciate me putting an input generator and validator into the question.

Comment: Btw, congratulations on posting question no. 3000! (Not counting deleted and locked questions.)

Comment: Oh wow. That's cool. I didn't even realize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## J - 77 char

Taking an approach that looks different from FUZxxl's answer but is actually very similar.

```
1!:2&4":2({.,|.@{.,@(256|$-0(0{[/:+`-/|@-])"1@|:(-#:1 2 3)|.!.0$)}.)0".1!:1]3
```

Some comments on the interesting bits.

- `1!:2&4":` (...) `0".1!:1]3` - If J wasn't terrible about I/O and parsing, this could be refactored as to use `&.".&.stdin''`, to save 3 chars. But it is so we can't. Rest in peace, precious characters.
- `2 ({.,|.@{.,@( ... stuff using $ ... )}.)` - This disassembles the input and reassembles the output. We use `$` both as a reference to the input in `stuff using $`, and as an operation we need to perform on the input before running the `stuff` on it.
- `0( blah )"1@|:` - Yes, that's a dyadic Transpose: we regroup the three rotation results as the innermost array axis, so that the Paeth logic can apply on each set separately with `"1`.
- `` 0{[/:+`-/|@-] `` - The Paeth logic: sort `a,b,c` by the magnitudes of (`p` minus each of `a,b,c`), and take the first.

Comment: This is really neat.

Comment: +1 for the dyadic transpose. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

### J, <s>97</s> <s>91</s> <s>88</s> 87 characters

Let's get this started. Notice the absent `exit`; J prints a prompt (three blanks) after all the output has been written, but then gets an EOF on `stdin`, causing it to terminate.

I believe that quite a couple of improvements are possible in this code.

```
1!:2&4":(|.@$,,)256|((-+`-/+[:(>&|{,)"0/]-"2+`-/)(3 2$-*i.3)|.!.0])2(|.@{.$}.)0".1!:1]3
```

Here is the code before golfing it; it's mostly equal to the current code.

```
NB. A, B, and C values
abc =: (0 _1 , _1 0 ,: _1 _1)&(|.!.0)
p =: +`-/@abc
NB. minimum of magnitudes
mmin =: (>&| { ,)"0
pred =: p + [: mmin/ abc -"2 2 p
paeth =: 256 | ] - pred
input =: [: (2&}. $~ 2 |.@{. ]) 0 ". 1!:1
output =: [: 1!:2&4 LF ,~ [: ": |.@$ , ,
output paeth input 3
exit 0
```

Comment: This code gives an incorrect output: `3 2$-*i:3` is not equivalent to `0 _1,_1 0,:_1 _1`.

Comment: @algorithmshark Sorry. better this way?